# SELECT column different from GROUP BY column in hierarchy structure

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I am using SQL to store information about a family tree. I want to be able to input the name of a person born in **Generation X** and output the names of all of their descendants born in **Generation Z**, but **only if these descendants are brother and sister** (have the same parent). I have found similar solutions, but I have found these solutions do not work with a hierarchical structure (due to aliasing). There may also be a parent and their child born in generation Y, so hierarchy depth is not reliable to determine Names.

```
+----+----------+-----------+------------+--------+
| ID | Name     | Parent_ID | Generation | Gender |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+--------+
| 1  | John     | NULL      | X          | Male   |
| 2  | Jill     | 1         | Y          | Female |
| 3  | Andy     | 2         | Z          | Male   |
| 4  | Ralph    | 2         | Z          | Male   |
| 5  | Lisa     | NULL      | X          | Female |
| 6  | Steve    | 5         | Y          | Male   |
| 7  | Sean     | 6         | Y          | Male   |
| 8  | Sarah    | 6         | Y          | Female |
| 9  | Emily    | 7         | Z          | Female |
| 10 | Matt     | 7         | Z          | Male   |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+--------+
```

Desired output: (if `SET @GenX = 'Lisa';`)

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| Emily |
| Matt  |
+-------+
```

This is my code so far.

```
SET @GenX = 'Lisa';

SELECT t2.name AS Kids
FROM (SELECT name, Parent_ID
    FROM FamilyTree
    WHERE Gender = 'Male' OR Gender = 'Female') t1
LEFT JOIN FamilyTree t2 ON t2.ID = t1.Parent_ID
LEFT JOIN FamilyTree t3 ON t3.ID = t2.Parent_ID
LEFT JOIN FamilyTree t4 ON t4.ID = t3.Parent_ID
WHERE t3.name = '@GenX' OR t4.name - '@GenX'
GROUP BY t2.name
HAVING SUM(t1.Gender) > 0 AND SUM(t1.Gender) > 0;
```

This returns the correct parent name, but does not return the kids names. If I `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the kids names, I can't find which kids have sisters/brothers. Thanks for the help. I'm really stuck on this one.

You may assume no repeated names or overlapping family trees.

Comment: Is their only 3 generations are their or more? and do you need the last generation names present in the table or the particular generation?

Comment: There may be more generations. So Generation Z is the important stopping point, but there could be a much larger tree that goes further back than Generation X. The number of people in a family line born during one generation may be variable (a parent and their child may both be born in a single generation)

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte
as
(
Select id,name,Parent_id,generation,gender from family_tree where name =@name and generation='x'
Union All
Select t.id, t.name,t.Parent_id,t.generation,t.gender from family_tree t          
join cte c on c. id=t.parent_id
)
,condition
as
(
select Parent_id,COUNT(*) cnt  from cte Where generation='z' Group by parent_id having COUNT(*)>1 
)
,sibling
as
(
select parent_id,Count(gender) cntg from 
        (select distinct c.parent_id,c.gender from cte c join condition co on co.parent_id=c.parent_id) a 
                group by parent_id having count(gender)>1

)        
select c.name from cte c join sibling s on c.parent_id=s.parent_id
```

Comment: FWIW, MySQL does not support CTE syntax until MySQL 8, which is still under development.

Comment: user has not mentioned mysql.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:mysql]. Tags are traditionally a way to communicate the brand of technology the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have only 3 generation you can go with the following query

```
   SELECT NAME FROM FamilyTree WHERE PARENT_ID IN 
    (SELECT ID FROM FamilyTree WHERE PARENT_ID IN
        (SELECT ID FROM FamilyTree WHERE PARENT_ID = 
            (SELECT ID FROM FamilyTree WHERE NAME = 'Lisa')
        )
    ) AND 
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM 
        (SELECT ID FROM FamilyTree WHERE PARENT_ID IN 
            (SELECT ID FROM FamilyTree WHERE PARENT_ID IN 
                (SELECT ID FROM FamilyTree WHERE PARENT_ID = 
                    (SELECT ID FROM FamilyTree WHERE NAME = 'Lisa')
                )
            )
        )T2 
    )=2 AND GENARATION = 'Z'
```

Above query will give result if their is only 3 generation
If its more you have to add more inner query and it will effect you performance.

Comment: Using the `IN` operator on a nested `SELECT` statement gave me the solution. I didn't realize the `IN` operator could be used on a subquery before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My original attempt returned the id's (names) of each parent of brother/sister Generation Z kids. The solution required using the `IN` operator to relate children's names to the parent id's given from the first nested `SELECT` statement.

```
SET @GenX = 'Lisa';

SELECT name FROM FamilyTree WHERE Parent_ID IN
    (SELECT t2.id AS Kids
    FROM
        (SELECT name, Parent_ID
        FROM FamilyTree
        WHERE Gender = 'Male' OR Gender = 'Female') t1
    -- Iterate through hierarchy        
    LEFT JOIN FamilyTree t2 ON t2.ID = t1.Parent_ID
    LEFT JOIN FamilyTree t3 ON t3.ID = t2.Parent_ID
    LEFT JOIN FamilyTree t4 ON t4.ID = t3.Parent_ID
    WHERE t3.name = '@GenX' OR t4.name - '@GenX'
    GROUP BY t2.id
    HAVING SUM(t1.Gender) > 0 AND SUM(t1.Gender) > 0); -- includes only brother/sister siblings
```